# ScriptSig raw hex to sign raw tx

Tags: bitcoin-core, raw-transaction, multi-signature, p2sh, ledger-hardware-wallet

i have a p2sh address that is created using an uncompressed public key (from my ledger nano) and a compressed public key (bitcoincore wallet). It requires both signatures to send the funds. When i use my nano ledger to sign i get output:

`3045022100b0c80ad5f5db6b790b75156186322b1fd6f9d1da61ff04e47f5a64ca8cdfaf6f02207bce077a537e215d9dd5ccaae72e8af1c4750e67722910c2af1d1f3b6e9357f2`

I am using the ledgerjs library to get this and using the signP2SHTransaction function. Normally i just input my private key into bitcoin core's `signrawtransaction` function but I am pretty sure this is the scriptSig. I just don't know of any libraries that allow me to use this to sign the rawtx. (I looked at python-bitcoinlib but i saw no way to input rawtx information into a readable format.)

Any suggestions on a tool i can use to take this to sign the raw tx hex to the send on the wire?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are signing 2-of-2 multisig, one key in core and one key in ledgerx?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, that is the `scriptSig`. I'm not sure if there exists a tool to add this to an unsigned tx, but you really just need to append it to the input you were signing. If you had multiple inputs, you need one of these for each input. Depending on your sighash flags, they may or may not be identical.